# Site hosted on App Engine, how to access images in cloud storage?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have a web application on App engine, data in Firestore and some images in cloud storage. I can communicate with Firestore fine to get data such as a filename with a file path:

Collection name 'Cats'

```
'name': 'Black Cat'
'filename': 'cat_black.jpg'
```

In cloud storage I have a  bucket named after the collection in firestore where my cat document is stored. In the bucket there is a jpg file called 'cat_black.jpg'. How do I link to this file in a secure way that only my app engine can fetch and display the photo?

```
# App Engine Web UI

<img src="https://storage.cloud.google.com/Cats/cat_black.jpg">
```

Do I need to edit the permissions on the bucket?

edit: I understand my App Engine creates its own bucket so it should by default have access to the bucket, will I need to retrieve the image in Python first? I'm thinking a jinja2 template function for each img src to run an API request and fetch its respective image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, when you create a bucket for your project, [your app has all the permissions required to read and write to it](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/setting-up-cloud-storage)

1. If you want to set permissions to allow other users to access the bucket and its contents, see [Setting bucket permissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cloud-console#_bucketpermission).
2. If you want to make it public with no authentication, you need (permissions allUsers to Reader)[https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public]

You can also check this instruction for [Setting Up Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/setting-up-cloud-storage) for some more details.

There are to ways to reference to the objects in the buckets:
`http://BUCKET_NAME.storage.googleapis.com/OBJECT_NAME`
or
`http://storage.googleapis.com/BUCKET_NAME/OBJECT_NAME`

Do not forget use to BUCKET_NAME.

Defaul AppEngine bucket has the name: `<project-id>.appspot.com`. Please be aware that it uses `projec-id` NOT project name. So to reference Default Storage Bucket you need to use following naming convention:

`http://<project-id>.appspot.com.storage.googleapis.com/OBJECT_NAME`
or
`http://storage.googleapis.com/<project-id>.appspot.com/OBJECT_NAME`

You do not need to retrieve image first in Python.

Comment: I'll give this another shot tomorrow! I feel like I did try doing something like that and it said I didn't have the credentials to do it but I had a "token". When I deployed my App Engine it created a bucket named after the Project, this is the bucket I'd need to use correct? eg. My project is called `cats`, and my bucket that got created got called `cats.appspot.com`, so would I reference it as `http://storage.googleapis.com/cats.appspot.com/cat_black.jpg`? Or would I create another bucket called anything, eg. `cat-photos` and then inherently my App should have access to it?

Comment: Please check updated answer. You do not need to create new bucket, but you can do it if you want. By default, when you create a bucket for your project, your app has all the permissions required to read and write to it.

Comment: Ohhh, ok! I'll have another go again tomorrow at work, will report back.

Comment: Does the bucket need to be public?

Comment: It depend on how you want to design authentication for your service/website. Please check updated answer. If you want to make it public with no authentication, you need (permissions allUsers to Reader)[https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public]